# 14.10 to 15.04 upgrade, now I can't poweroff or reboot!

Tags: upgrade, 15.04, shutdown, reboot, systemd

I was previously running 14.10 without any problems on an Intel NUC Bay trail but then after upgrading it to 15.04 my PC won't poweroff or reboot anymore. At the shutdown messages it says umounting filesystems then "Reached target Shutdown." at that point it just stops, forcing me to press the power button to reboot it.

Comment: How are you getting it to shutdown and/or reboot? Are doing it through Terminal or the GUI?

Comment: Through the Terminal.

Comment: did you find a solution? This is bothering me also...

Comment: I gave up as it appears to be the poor BIOS that affectes the Intel NUCs. Sold the NUC and got a Gigabyte Brix 2955U instead - works flawless.

Comment: I'm still having this same issue as well.

Answer (score 1):

First this is [bug #1464917:](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1464917)
If this affects you please go there and let them know.
After the shutdown or reboot has hanged with this message

`Reached target Shutdown`

You will only see this if you have removed the splash screen

Try [Sysrq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key)

1. Hold down the Alt and SysRq (Print Screen) keys.
2. While holding those down, type the following keys in order, several
   seconds apart: REISUB
3. Computer should reboot.

Once it reboots immediately try shutdown button again, it should shutdown properly.  Please add your name to the "This Affects Me" button at launchpad bug link above

You can also try the following after it hangs.

see if you can login tty1 and reboot

1. Press `Ctrl+Alt+F1` or `Ctrl+Alt+F2` or `Ctrl+Alt+F3` ...
2. Write your username (lowercase, the name of the user folder in
   /home) and hit Enter
3. Write your password (nothing will appear) and hit Enter

If your password and username are correct, you are now logged in.

If that fails try `Ctrl+Alt+Del` a couple times at that point in the tty1 screen

You might see a message that states the machine is going to reboot and then it should do just that after a minute or so.

Its better than a hard boot - until its fixed

In the bug notes it is reported that you can upgrade to Vivid-Proposed and it fixes the issue but some still see this after that upgrade.  It might be worth a shot.

Btw the same bug affects me and I have not tried the upgrade yet but the steps I listed do work.